# Ruby/Watir :no such file to load -- spreadsheet (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, excel, watir

I am using the Spreadsheet GEM to parse an excel file for my Ruby/Watir Project. I have all the necessary Gems as shown by the Gems List below :

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
 archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
 builder (3.2.2)
 bundler (1.5.2)
 childprocess (0.4.0)
 columnize (0.3.6)
 cucumber (1.3.10)
 data_magic (0.17)
 dbi (0.4.5)
 debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.1)
 deprecated (3.0.1, 2.0.1)
 diff-lcs (1.2.5)
 faker (1.2.0)
 ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
 gherkin (2.12.2 x86-mingw32)
 i18n (0.6.9)
 minitest (5.2.2)
 multi_json (1.8.4)
 multi_test (0.0.3)
 page-object (0.9.5)
 page_navigation (0.9)
 rake (10.1.1)
 rdoc (2.5.8)
 require_all (1.3.2)
 rspec (2.14.1)
 rspec-core (2.14.7)
 rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
 rspec-mocks (2.14.5)
 ruby-ole (1.2.11.7)
 ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
 rubygems-update (2.2.1)
 rubyzip (1.1.0)
 selenium-webdriver (2.39.0)
 spreadsheet (0.9.7)
 test-unit (2.5.5)
 testgen (0.8.5)
 thor (0.18.1)
 tiny_tds (0.6.1 x86-mingw32)
 watir-webdriver (0.6.6)
 websocket (1.1.2, 1.0.7)
 win32console (1.3.2 x86-mingw32)
 yml_reader (0.2)
```

I still obtain the:

```
no such file to load -- spreadsheet (LoadError)
C:/Users/ppai/Desktop/Cucumber Watir/demo     (2)/demo/features/step_definitions/Function.rb:4:in `require'
C:/Users/ppai/Desktop/Cucumber Watir/demo (2)/demo/features/step_definitions/Function.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in `run!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

When I run the code :

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'win32ole'
 require 'watir-webdriver'
 require "spreadsheet"
 Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
 book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
 book = Spreadsheet.open 'C:\\Users\\mndd\\Desktop\\Cucumber\\Watir\\demo (2)\\demo\\Test.xls'
```

I have all the solutions (update Gems, re-install spreadsheet GEM etc.) given for previous queries on the same error, but was unable to resolve it. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Attached code to the question

Comment: Not quite a solution, but I bet using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) to explicitly specify what gems your application needs will fix this issue.